# Will a shop which takes health take armoured hearts first?

Tags: ascendant

If I buy something from a shop which costs health, will it bypass any armoured hearts I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A shop which takes health as payment works the same as normal damage in that it will first take your armoured hearts, then your regular hearts.